# Convert Image into background image

Tags: php, html, css

I have working code that gets a image inside a div, but when I check it mobile the image is too small and when I increse its height it gets desproporcional so im trying to get it into a background image.

What I have at the moment:

```
 <div class="carousel-item '; if ($num == 0) {echo ' active ';} echo'" >
    <img class="d-block w-100 h-100" src="'.substr($leaderboard->$topbd_ContentImg,3).'" alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" style="position:fixed; top: 10%;">
         <h5>'.$leaderboard->$topbd_ContentMenu.'</h5>
         <div class="space-15"></div>
         <p style="font-size:185%;">'.$stringaux.'</p>
         <span class="d-none d-lg-block">
            <div class="space-10"></div>
            <a href="'.$url.'"><img src="static/img/leaderboard-seta.png" /></a>
         </span>
      </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

I tried putting `img class="d-block w-100 h-100"`, into `div class="carousel-item` to use as a background with no sucess.

How do I do to make the image a background insted of just inserting the image?

Comment: Do you try to use CSS property `background-image` ?

Comment: Your using some kind of CSS Library, please include the name of that.

Comment: If you're using bootstrap, you could use the class `responsive`. You could also try the css property background-image if the element itself is responsive. In any case, you could also look into media queries to style independantly depending on the size of the device (i.e. when you reach a specific screen width etc.)

Comment: @jouby yes i tried using backgroun-image

Comment: @Anuga I think I'm only using bootstrap

Comment: @Martin The problem with using reponsive or ```class="img-fluid"``` is that image becomes streched and I don't want it to get strech, I want it to keep the same ration even if it cuts some part of the image.

Comment: hahaha strangely I got the notification of your comment, Pbras - rather than the other Martin. Maybe Martin can tweak his username? `:-/`

Comment: Lol, how do I mention him then?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your image to be a background for the whole of carousel item? 
If so, then this might work:

```
<div class="carousel-item '; if ($num == 0) {echo ' active ';} echo'" style="background-image:url('.substr($leaderboard->$topbd_ContentImg,3).')">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" style="position:fixed; top: 10%;">
        <h5>'.$leaderboard->$topbd_ContentMenu.'</h5>
        <div class="space-15"></div>
        <p style="font-size:185%;">'.$stringaux.'</p>
        <span class="d-none d-lg-block">
          <div class="space-10"></div>
        <a href="'.$url.'"><img src="static/img/leaderboard-seta.png" /></a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

In addition to that you would have to add the following css to `.carousel-item`

```
.carousel-item{
       background-position: center center;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-size: cover;
    }
```

The background-position is optional and allows you to modify how to align those images, you might want to read up on this css property and its options.

Comment: Tried it but doesnt work, when I do this the entire division becomes blank.

Comment: @Pbras Try using `background-image: url()` to link to an actual image in your project (without a variable). If that works there's something wrong with how you resolve the background-image in the inline-css.